# Is there an equivalent to the distributive law for division over subtraction and/or addition?

Tags: arithmetic

I understand that the the distributive law cannot be applied to division over addition/subtraction, but is there an equivalent law to expand it out.  For example, I know:
$$100 \times (5 + 3) = (100 \times 5) + (100 \times 3),$$
but with
$$100 \div (5 + 3),$$
I can't do (that is, is not equal to)
$$(100 \div 5) + (100\div 3).$$

Is there a way I can "distribute" when it is division over addition/subtraction?

Comment: Just like addition is associative and commutative but subtraction is not, multiplication distributes over sums, is commutative and associative, but division is not. You can "distribute" if you have a sum *followed* by a division, $$(a+b)/c = (a/c) + (b/c)$$but not the other way around, because "dividing by $c$" is really the same as "multiplying by the reciprocal of $c$"; but because in general there is no relation between the reciprocal of $a+b$ and the reciprocals of $a$ and of $b$, in general there is no simple relation between dividing by $a+b$ and divisions by $a$ and by $b$.

Comment: Thanks Arturo, it makes sense, I was afraid that would be the answer.  I happen to have my division followed by my subtraction/addition, so I guess I am stuck with no distribution :)

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac ab + \dfrac ac = a\left( \dfrac 1b + \dfrac 1c \right) 
= a(b+c) \div (bc)   $